# Troubleshoot load balancer tab don't show on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have created 2 EC2 instances and I have installed and configured the installation of Apache Server on both instances.In addition, the ports 22 and 80 are open. When I select the Load Balancers button, nothing is shown. The same happens with other utilities, such as Instance Types, etc. Can you please tell me what to do?

[image: screenshot with the problem]

Answer (score 1):

Login via incognito window, it’s likely a broken browser cache.

If not take a look at your console window and see if any noticeable error

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. Yes, there is a console error!! DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for https://eu-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/v2/bootstrap.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

Comment: Haha, classic AWS rolling things out. Hopefully it’ll resolve soon :)

Comment: So, there isn't anything I could do, is there?

Comment: If it’s that as the JS error then it’s AWS. It’s likely a bad cache in CloudFront that’s causing it for them. Give it a little bit and it should clear. Or try relogging in :)

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the browser cache or opening in an incognito window.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried it but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Other ideas: Try holding the SHIFT key while clicking the Reload button. Also, try changing the size of the window in case there is a CSS problem. Try in a different browser (Chrome vs Firefox).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you again very much for your responses. I realized that it is a cache problem of chrome and I opened the mozilla firefox instead of google chrome browzer and it worked.